# tf.keras.model.fit taking a long time

Tags: pandas, csv, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am training a TF2 neural network on Titanic data and for some reason it's taking way too long to process even one epoch I even left it for 15 minutes but it still keeps looping over epoch 1/10 without showing the progress bar. Is there something wrong with the model or with the way I converted CSV to NumPy array (from the jupyter notebook I used it didnt show any error whatsoever).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

TRAIN_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv"
TEST_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv"

train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
test_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("eval.csv", TEST_DATA_URL)

train = pd.read_csv(train_file_path)
test = pd.read_csv(test_file_path)

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

df = pd.concat([train, test])

df = df.drop(['class', 'embark_town', 'age', 'fare', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch'], axis=1)

df.info()

X = df.values
y = df['survived'].values

X = np.delete(X, 0, axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `one-hot encoding` of features. I have one-hot encoded every feature here which is an overkill you can specify which columns to encode manually.

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

TRAIN_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv"
TEST_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv"

train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
test_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("eval.csv", TEST_DATA_URL)

train = pd.read_csv(train_file_path)
test = pd.read_csv(test_file_path)

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

df = pd.concat([train, test])

df = df.drop(['class', 'embark_town', 'age', 'fare', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch'], axis=1)

df.info()

y = df['survived'].values
X = df.values
X = np.delete(X, 0, axis=1)

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = enc.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=1)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 891 entries, 0 to 263
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   survived  891 non-null    int64 
 1   sex       891 non-null    object
 2   deck      891 non-null    object
 3   alone     891 non-null    object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 34.8+ KB
Epoch 1/100
20/20 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.7805 - accuracy: 0.6565
Epoch 2/100 .........
```

Comment: Thanks dude, that really helped and solved my problem.

Comment: I am new to Deep Learning so could you briefly explain what does the OneHotEncoder do? and when to use it?

Comment: If you have two categories: `[1, 2]`. One Hot encoding will convert it to `[[1. 0], [0, 1]]`. It helps in converting various categories into ML compatible entities. You should read more about it as this comment does not do justice to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of your data is not numeric, you should change it using for example [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot). You should get en error like I did, hard to say why no stacktrace was displayed